# How to set go module path of private repository

Tags: go, go-modules

I want to set my go module path to `example.com/myrepo` instead of `github.com/myusername/myrepo` such that I am able to import in inside another repository.

for example, if my go.mod looks like this

```
module example.com/myrepo

go 1.13
```

how will I make `go get example.com/myrepo` work?

I am getting the following on `go get example.com/myrepo`

```sh
unrecognized import path "example.com/myrepo" (parse https://example.com/myrepo?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

Given I am the owner of `example.com` how can I do this?

Comment: OK. What problem are you having with doing that?

Comment: Try to go in the parent folder and type "go mod init". This will create go.mod and go.sum file

Comment: Is the `example.com/myrepo` a valid Git repo?

Comment: @Adrian I can create a repo with module name `mydomain.com/myrepo`, but unable to do `go get mydomain.com/myrepo`

Comment: @AmitBasuri: have you setup the infrastructure to allow fetching modules from `mydomain.com`?

Comment: @JimB no, how to do it?

Comment: @AmitBasuri: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Answer (score 2):

it is called **vanity import paths**.

In addition to the common hosting sites (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc) and custom VCS URLs (.git, .hg, etc) known to the go command, this mechanism can be used to point a custom URL to any of the services.

you must be looking for this https://sagikazarmark.hu/blog/vanity-import-paths-in-go/.

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”